# Which one does Google prefer, Microdata or JSON-LD?

Tags: google-search, microdata, json-ld

Here [Google says they prefer JSON-LD](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data#markup-formats-and-placement):

> **JSON-LD is the recommended format**. Google is in the process of adding
>   JSON-LD support for all markup-powered features. The table below lists
>   the exceptions to this. We recommend using JSON-LD where possible.

But in other article, in the *What is microdata and JSON-LD markup?* section, [they say they prefer microdata for content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/3069489?topic=3070267&hl=en):

> Microdata and JSON-LD are two different ways to mark up your data
>   using the schema.org vocabulary. It's best to choose either microdata
>   or JSON-LD and avoid using both types on a single page or email.
>   **Google prefers microdata for web content**.

So what's up?

Comment: JSON-LD support is the newest: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/01/new-structured-data-testing-tool.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The document that recommends JSON-LD is more recent and it clearly states that Google recommends using JSON-LD where possible (over Microdata) specifically for [the following reasons](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data#markup-formats-and-placement):

- "The markup does not have to be interleaved with the user-visible text, which makes nested data items easier to express, such as the Country of a PostalAddress of a MusicVenue of an Event."
- "Google can read JSON-LD data when it is dynamically injected into the page's contents, such as by JavaScript code or embedded widgets in your content management system."

Answer (score 1):

The [Google Developers article](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data#markup-formats-and-placement) is more recent. Then, I would choose that information as the prefered one.