# SEO/Schema/JSON-LD: In order to better index/rank, should I use: Yoast with JSON-LD? Microdata with JSON-LD? or everything with JSON-LD?

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, rich-snippets, json-ld, markup

**Context:**

1 - Our corporate website is custom developed on Wordpress, with AMP in mind.

2- The website has the following structure, and JSON-LD Schema lineup:

- Home Page - 1 page - `Website, Webpage, Breadcrumb`
- About Page - 1 page - `Organization, Webpage, Action, MediaObject, BreadcrumbList`
- Sub-About Pages - 15 pages - `Webpage, Action, MediaObject, Breadcrumb`
- Services Page - 1 page - `OfferCatalog, Webpage, Action, MediaObject, Breadcrumb`
- Sub-Services Pages - 5 pages - `Service, OfferCatalog, Webpage, Action, MediaObject, Breadcrumb`
- Solutions Page - 1 page - `Product, OfferCatalog, Webpage, Action, MediaObject, Breadcrumb`
- Sub-Solutions Pages - 3 pages - `Product, OfferCatalog, Webpage, Action, MediaObject, Breadcrumb`
- Industries - 1 page - `Webpage, Action, MediaObject, Breadcrumb`
- Sub-Industries - 15 pages - `Webpage, FAQPage, Action, MediaObject`
- Portfolio - 1 page - `Webpage, MediaObject`
- Sub-Portfolio - infinite - `Webpage, Review, MediaObject`
- News - 1 page - `Webpage, Action, MediaObject`
- Sub-News - infinite - `Article, FAQPage, Review, Action, MediaObject`
- Contact - 1 page - `Webpage, Action, MediaObject, Breadcrumb`

3- Our goal is to index for short and long-tail keywords, this means being as transparent and accessible to search bots.

**Question**

In order to better index/rank, should I use: Yoast with JSON-LD? Microdata with JSON-LD? or everything with JSON-LD?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter what type of structured data you use because Google doesn't use structured data as a signal for what should be indexed or how it should rank.   See my blog post on the subject: [SEO Myth: Structured data helps search engine rankings](https://blog.ostermiller.org/structured-data-seo/).

The biggest reason to implement structured data is to get [rich snippets](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/search-gallery): a special display for your site in the search results.  Rich snippets can increase your click through rate and get more visitors to your site from the search results.

Of the types that you mention, `Breadcrumb` and `Article` do get rich snippets, but they tend to be low value.   They don't appear often enough or specially enough to drive a significant number of extra clicks.  If your organization is a local business (has a physical store front that customers can visit), your `Organization` schema could be valuable, but otherwise there isn't much point.

It is really only worth implementing structured data if you have data that fits the higher value rich snippets like recipes or user reviews.

Google supports both Microdata and JSON-LD, so it doesn't matter which one you choose.  Google will be able to read it either way.

Microdata has the advantage that you don't need to repeat your data, you just mark it up in the page where it already exists.

JSON-LD gets its own section which tends not to break when the page is changed, but it does repeat all the data and there is no mechanism to ensure that the included data actually appears on the page.  (If data isn't included on the page Google will ignore it or even penalize your site for spamming.)

For more information see [Which one does Google prefer, Microdata or JSON-LD?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/102174/which-one-does-google-prefer-microdata-or-json-ld)